# How to remove a callback function from jQuery widget

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, callback, widget

I have a widget that I am assigning a callback function to for a specific event.

The following code works and triggers my callback just fine.

```
$(selector).MyFancyWidget('option', 'onComplete', this._onComplete);
```

My issue is after the event fires I want to remove the callback from inside the _onComplete method.

onComplete is an event that gets fired in the widget using the _trigger method and works fine.
Doing something like

```
$(selector).MyFancyWidget('option', 'onComplete', $.noop);
```

Does not detach the callback ( i assume it is just adding another listener.

For clarity here is the code inside the widget that will trigger the event.

```
instance._trigger('onComplete', e, {currentTarget: instance});
```

So my question here is how do I remove that callback?
It's not that I don't want to fire the event anymore I just don't want to listen to it anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way of doing this would be to make the callback only do something once. So wherever you define your `_oncomplete` function:

```
var completeRan = false;
this._onComplete = function(e, args) {
    if (completeRan) {
        return;
    }
    // Rest of your code.
    completeRan = true;
    return this;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid a work around like this but if nobody comes up with anything better I may just have to go this route.